# How can i run Javascript outside of Angular AFTER Angular Has finished rendering of HTML DOM?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add script to a running site (via console) that manipulate the view.
I want to run it every time angular finishes rendering and loading the page.
how it can be done?

Comment: One simple question: Why?

Comment: It would be helpful if you expose the use case. The question is too wide

Comment: @lin some ppl might do this to pre-populate form data by hooking into the client models and letting the MV binding take care of it. I've created snippets in Chrome for this very reason to access angular models to pre-populate a very long input form. Not sure if this is what the OP is intending or not though...